# What is an approach / existing system / research efford to provide information how was prepared a BI report?

Tags: database, user-interface, analytics, business-intelligence

I am looking for information what are approaches or existing systems that let an end user of a BI system to have insight how data in the report was prepared/processed. In my case, an advanced BI user would like to know, e.g., an insight which databases were integrated in a ETL process (maybe something was missed) or Information Quality filter applied (could cause loosing important data). My aim is to learn about solutions -- the best -- deployed in a real world scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as "How can we show the users the story / business rules behind the numbers we show".

If I am right, you may be able to allow the users to drill down the detail data using which summary data is built. It can be very difficult in most cases since it is data + business logic at that point in time. So the best bet would be start showing the business rules in the reports (the report specifications?). For business critical reports which summarise information, you can have detail reports as a subreport as well (and also mention any business rules applied as much as possible)